# Unable to capture Modal close event if user click on 'X' sign

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, moodle

Hi Everyone I am writing a code where I am asking the user if previous activity detected they want to ask from where they left. I am able to handle save and cancel events very well. but I am unable to handle the 'x'(close) event where user click on x sign and the modal disappear

1. if user is clicking on save(Yes) button. it will set the video time where the left.
2. if they click cancel it will ask for a confirmation "are you sure".
3. even if user click outside of the modal. I am able to capture it with outsideClick event

these are working fine. but I just noticed when I click on 'x'. nothing is happening. but I want to show the same message as cancel if user click on 'x' . I tried with the destroyed method but its not working

attaching photothis is modal showing and events working well. but now if I will click on 'x' top right close button..

here is my code snippet

```
`hiddenbtn.on('click', function() {

ModalFactory.create({
    type: ModalFactory.types.SAVE_CANCEL,
    title: 'Previous Activity Detected',
    // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
    body: 'Do you want to start from where You left?',
    // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
}).then(function(modal) {
    modal.setSaveButtonText('Yes');
    let root = modal.getRoot();
    root.on(ModalEvents.save, function() {
        recognition.videoTempid.currentTime = data.timestamp;
    });
    root.on(ModalEvents.cancel, function() {
        modalHandler();
    });
    root.on(ModalEvents.outsideClick, function() {
        modalHandler();
    });
    modal.show();
});
});`
```

ModalHandler is my another function.
Main question is which event I should try or how can i capture if user press 'X' button then i want to call my ModalHandler function
[This cross sign on top left 'X'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We2oU.png)

I tried hidden event also but if I use hidden event my all events are executing .save,.cancel.outsideclick .

how can I get capture this close event?

[Bootstrap modal close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267816/bootstrap-modal-close-event)

I tried this but problem is my id of modal is generated by Moodle so its random. it didn't not work for me

Answer (score 1):

Hi I just read through all predefined files of MOdal_factory.js and Modal.js
where I found we can use selector to find the element and hide it

```
modal.modal.find('.close').hide();
```

so now This x sign is disappear and I can use click method to capture the event as well